# NodeJS Clusters, Socket.io rooms , child processes

Tags: node.js, socket.io, child-process, node-cluster

If user A connects to the server through child process 1 and joins a room
and user B connects to the server through child process 2 and joins the same room as user A (same id as user A)

will they end up in the same room or they will have completely different rooms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For node.js Cluster, each child process has its own memory space which means they cannot share memory directly.so A connect and B connect will have completely different rooms.

I solved a similar problem in the past and used https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/adapter to solve socket.io connection with different communication processes.